# Django 1.1 date-based generic view problem - archive_year, archive_month, archive_day

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

I'm on my first Django blog and when trying to get the posts by year, month and day, using the built-in generic view from Django, but I don't get proper results. *(Sorry for my non-professional first question.. if someone knows what is the appropriate question, please let me know)*

Well, I think it's better to show you my configuration to make yourself a better picture:

### Complete blog URLconf:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

from weblog.models import Entry

entry_info_dict = {
    'queryset': Entry.published,
    'date_field': 'pub_date',
    'template_object_name': 'Entry',
    }

urlpatterns = patterns('django.views.generic.date_based',
      (r'^$', 'archive_index', entry_info_dict, 'weblog_entry_archive_index'),
      (r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/$',
       'archive_year', entry_info_dict,
       'weblog_entry_archive_year'),
      (r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\w{3})/$',
       'archive_month',
       entry_info_dict,
       'weblog_entry_archive_month'),
      (r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\w{3})/(?P<day>\d{2})/$',
       'archive_day',
       entry_info_dict,
       'weblog_entry_archive_day'),
      (r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\w{3})/(?P<day>\d{2})/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$',
       'object_detail',
       entry_info_dict,
       'weblog_entry_detail'),
)
```

### urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
(r'^blog/', include('weblog.urls.entries')),
...
)
```

### entry_archive_year.html:

```
            <h2>Archive for {{ year }}</h2>
            <ul>
                    {% for month in pub_date %}
                    <li>
                            <a href="/blog/{{ year }}/{{ month|date:"b" }}/">{{ month|date:"F" }}</a>
                    </li>
                    {% endfor %}
            </ul>
```

Supposing I have the following blog entry:

example.com/blog/2009/dec/18/test

and now request

example.com/blog/2009/

I get no objects, though when giving the full URL the post is shown.

**I think Django is failing silently somewhere, though it's in DEBUG mode, and I can't figure out where.
I'd appreciate any support with this one.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The month information is stored in the context variable `date_list`, not `pub_date`.

From the django docs for [`archive_year`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/generic-views/#django-views-generic-date-based-archive-year):

> **Template context:**
>
> In addition to `extra_context`, the
>   template's context will be:
>
> - `date_list`: A list of datetime.date objects representing all
>     months that have objects available in
>     the given year, according to queryset,
>     in ascending order.

The following should do the trick:

```
{% for month in date_list %}
    <li>
        <a href="/blog/{{ year }}/{{ month|date:"b" }}/">{{ month|date:"F" }}</a>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: that's it.. I missed the point with `pub_date`. Thanks Alasdair